# Decompress chunk where shouldnt be

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb, ignition

I have an Ignition installation feeding into a Postgres DB with TimescaleDB. The setup is as follows :

- Postgres 15
- Hypertable with 100 parallel chunks, 12h interval
- Autocompression set to 24h

In theory, no data should need to be decompressed, unless I query > 24h from now, yet, when I do this :

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE 
SELECT 
    "tagid","intvalue","floatvalue","stringvalue","datevalue","t_stamp","dataintegrity" 
FROM 
    sqlth_1_data 
WHERE  
    "t_stamp">cast(extract(epoch from now()) - extract(epoch from INTERVAL '4 hours') as BIGINT)*1000 
ORDER BY 
    "t_stamp" DESC
```

I get a slow query that decompresses chunks, same if I try with 10 minutes. Is my query wrong ? Or is the setup wrong ?

Comment: The chunks can be excluded in advance, you're right. 

have you checked other alternative syntax like static timestamp values? Maybe the problem is with the `extract(epoch`?

As query plan  hooks are very specific to sql syntax, maybe it's some syntax that is uncovered.

Comment: @jonatasdp, I'll try, but theoretically this should be resolved first, and the query should behave the same with static values.

Comment: @jonatasdp You were right, it absolutely speed things up when using a static value.