# Slow performance when querying continuous aggregate with time_bucket_gapfill despite relatively small data set

Tags: indexing, time-series, materialized-views, timescaledb, continuous-aggregates

```
CREATE TABLE sku_usage (
    -- create a regular table
    time timestamptz NOT NULL,
    device_id uuid NOT NULL,
    loyalty_program_id text NOT NULL,
    sku text NOT NULL,
    quantity double precision NOT NULL,
    transaction_id text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (time, device_id, sku, transaction_id)
);

SELECT
    create_hypertable ('sku_usage', 'time');

CREATE INDEX ix_device_sku_time ON sku_usage (time, device_id, sku_id DESC);
```

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW sku_usage_hourly
WITH (timescaledb.continuous) AS
    SELECT
        time_bucket('1 hour', time) AS bucket,
        device_id,
        sku,
        SUM(quantity)
    FROM sku_usage
    GROUP BY bucket, device_id, sku
    WITH NO DATA;
```

```
SELECT add_continuous_aggregate_policy('sku_usage_hourly',
start_offset => INTERVAL '3 hours',
end_offset => INTERVAL '1 hour',
schedule_interval => INTERVAL '1 hour');
```

I then threw in 20 million rows

When I run this query

```
(
    SELECT
        time_bucket_gapfill ('1 hour', bucket) AS time_bucket,
        device_id,
        sku,
        coalesce(max(sum), 0) AS usage
    FROM
        sku_usage_hourly
    WHERE
        bucket < now() - INTERVAL '100 days'
        AND bucket > now() - INTERVAL '110 days'
        AND device_id IN ('111109ee-aaaa-4444-8765-123450273214')
        AND sku IN ('10-49-0920')
    GROUP BY
        time_bucket,
        device_id,
        sku
);
```

it always takes about 6-6.5 seconds to run (0.5 CPU, 2 GB RAM). I am shocked it is so slow. It is only producing about 2200 rows.

If I do

```
select count(*) from sku_usage where
        time < now() - INTERVAL '100 days'
        AND time > now() - INTERVAL '110 days'
        AND device_id IN ('111109ee-aaaa-4444-8765-123450273214')
        AND sku IN ('10-49-0920')
```

It returns about 1000 records in 400ms. If I remove the device and sku conditions, there is only ~3500000

Why is my `time_bucket_gapfill` so slow? How can I improve it?

My understanding is that the materialized view should have the index (bucket, device_id, sku). Is it not being used properly? Or is the `time_bucket_gapfill` doing something weird?

Thanks

EDIT: changing my query to just

```
SELECT
        device_id,
    FROM
        sku_usage_hourly
    WHERE
        bucket < now() - INTERVAL '100 days'
        AND bucket > now() - INTERVAL '110 days'
        AND device_id IN ('111109ee-aaaa-4444-8765-123450273214')
        AND sku IN ('10-49-0920')
```

still takes 6 seconds. so it isn't the time_bucket_gapfill.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share what you have in the query planner?

Have you tried to change the `AND device_id IN (...)` to `AND device_id =` ?

Same for the other param that uses `IN`.

Comment: Similar query plan issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77530457/decompress-chunk-where-shouldnt-be?noredirect=1#comment136725160_77530457